# Hierarchial query debugging

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

What I am trying to do is from the admissions table I would like to know the names of the patients who had visited the hospital more than twice for the last 30 days from each visit date. I came up with the below query with CTE and Ideally it should be retuning only two names but its returning 3. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

```
create table admissions(Patient_id int, patient_name varchar(50),   visitdate datetime);

insert into admissions (patient_id, patient_name, visitdate) values(1,  'Victor',   cast('2014-04-10 22:01:13.373' as datetime));
insert into admissions (patient_id, patient_name, visitdate) values(1,  'Victor',   cast('2014-06-14 22:01:53.923' as datetime));
insert into admissions (patient_id, patient_name, visitdate) values(1,  'Victor',   cast('2014-04-15 22:01:53.927' as datetime));
insert into admissions (patient_id, patient_name, visitdate) values(1,  'Victor',   cast('2014-04-19 22:01:53.960' as datetime));
insert into admissions (patient_id, patient_name, visitdate) values(1,  'Victor',   cast('2014-04-30 22:01:53.963' as datetime));
insert into admissions (patient_id, patient_name, visitdate) values(2,  'Sam',      cast('2014-04-25 22:04:32.547' as datetime));
insert into admissions (patient_id, patient_name, visitdate) values(2,  'Sam',      cast('2014-04-25 22:04:56.287' as datetime));
insert into admissions (patient_id, patient_name, visitdate) values(2,  'Sam',      cast('2014-06-14 22:04:56.290' as datetime));
insert into admissions (patient_id, patient_name, visitdate) values(2,  'Sam',      cast('2014-09-22 22:04:56.290' as datetime));
insert into admissions (patient_id, patient_name, visitdate) values(2,  'Sam',      cast('2015-04-05 22:04:56.290' as datetime));
insert into admissions (patient_id, patient_name, visitdate) values(3,  'Tony',     cast('2014-04-25 22:45:42.203' as datetime));
insert into admissions (patient_id, patient_name, visitdate) values(3,  'Tony',     cast('2012-10-22 22:45:42.203' as datetime));
insert into admissions (patient_id, patient_name, visitdate) values(3,  'Tony',     cast('2010-05-06 22:45:42.247' as datetime));
insert into admissions (patient_id, patient_name, visitdate) values(3,  'Tony',     cast('2001-08-01 22:45:42.247' as datetime));
insert into admissions (patient_id, patient_name, visitdate) values(3,  'Tony',     cast('2019-05-14 23:07:05.340' as datetime));

--Below query should return only two records only for (Victor and Sam)
```

```html
with CTE (patient_id, patient_name, visitdate, diff, ranked) as
(
select patient_id, patient_name, visitdate, diff, ranked from
(select 
 patient_id patient_id,
 patient_name patient_name,
 visitdate visitdate, 
 cast(0 as integer) diff,
 rank() over(partition by patient_id order by visitdate desc) ranked
from admissions) a where ranked = 1

union all

select 
 test.patient_id patient_id,
 test.patient_name patient_name,
 test.visitdate visitdate,
 cast((cte.visitdate - test.visitdate)  as integer)diff,
 test.ranked ranked
from (select 
 patient_id patient_id,
 patient_name patient_name,
 visitdate visitdate, 
 rank() over(partition by patient_id order by visitdate desc) ranked
from admissions) test
inner join CTE
 on test.patient_id = CTE.patient_id
 and test.ranked = cte.ranked + 1
where (cte.visitdate - test.visitdate) <=31 
and cte.visitdate <> test.visitdate
)

select * from CTE;
```

Comment: Why are you adding 1 to the patient_id (the +1)?

Comment: Hi... It was wrong... I shouldn't have incremented the patient_id. It should have been the rank value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't quite get what you wanted (what you stated you wanted doesn't match with Sam and Victor - Sam's 1st 2 rows are the only ones within 30 days of each other, and that means only 1 visit within 30 days of another) but try this

```
select distinct
    a.patient_id,
    a.patient_name
from admissions a 
inner join admissions b on 
    a.patient_id = b.patient_id and
    b.visitdate >= (a.visitdate - 30) and 
    b.visitdate < a.visitdate
group by 
    a.patient_id,
    a.patient_name,
    a.visitdate
having
    count(b.visitdate) >= 1
```

This returns all patients who have had 1 or more visits within 30 days of a visit (or basically 2 visits in a 30 day window)

If you want to add more conditions (like within 30 days of the patient's LAST visit, or 2 or more, etc.) you should be able to add the other conditions quite easily.

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4831e/13

Comment: Can the same be achieved through a recursive CTE?

Comment: I don't think a recursive cte would be meaningful